# Need to create new column of converting data into facor levels using mutate and if

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

`cell.data <- cell.data%>%mutate(Overage.factor=ifelse(cell.data$OverageFee==0|cell.data$OverageFee<=5.0,"Overage<5",                                                    ifelse(cell.data$OverageFee>5.0|cell.data$OverageFee<=10.0,"ovearge<10",                                             ifelse(cell.data$OverageFee>10.0|cell.data$OverageFee<=15.0,"overage>10","overage>15"))))`

Getting output only for levels like Overage<5 & ovearge<10.

Comment: If you want your new variable to have the value "overage<10" when `OverageFee` is between 5 and 10, and etc .. You will need to replace all your `|` (OR) by `&` (AND).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. Without data, I cannot test it. You may want to try something like this:

```
cell.data <- cell.data%>%
  mutate(Overage.factor=case_when(
    (OverageFee>=0 & OverageFee<=5.0) ~ "Overage<5",
    (OverageFee>5.0 & OverageFee<=10.0) ~ "ovearge<10",
    (OverageFee>10.0 & OverageFee<=15.0) ~ "overage>10",
    TRUE ~"overage>15"))
```

Comment: Thanks ..it worked..but why iflese didn't worked..

Comment: Because the logic of using `|` in your code. `>5 | <=10` include any values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special function which will make this work a lot easier! See `dplyr::case_when`

Here is a example:

```
library(tidyverse)

values <- sample(1:99,10)

case_when(values <= 59 ~ 10,
          values == 60 ~ 60,
          values >= 61 ~ 99)
```

Good luck